# Map tiles appearing black in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm having a problem with one map tile in QGIS. It appears like this when zoomed out:

[image]

But it appears normal when zoomed in:

[image]

A colleague has tried the same tile in MapInfo, where it appeared fine at any scale, but I'm still having problems in QGIS.

Comment: You could try rebuilding the pyramids. Layer Properties> Pyramids> Build pyramids (from bottom right corner)

Comment: if this is ordnance survey 1:25k lzw tiffs you might need to uncompress or covert to png.

Comment: Converting to a png has solved the initial problem, but now the tile appears in the wrong place, despite selecting the correct coordinate system.